# Spring data neo4j tutorial for beginners

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

Is there any comprehensive spring data tutorial for neo4j for a complete newbie. I know cypher and Java, but I have no experience in things like JPA. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything for beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Spring Data Neo4j 4, here are two resources-

A short guide to building an application with Spring Data Neo4j 4: https://www.airpair.com/neo4j/posts/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4

The reference covers SDN4 in greater detail- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1

Finally, there are a couple of sample applications-

- https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university
- https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-northwind
- https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-conference